# Looking for Java-based alternative to OpenSCAD and PLasM

Tags: java, python, cgal, openscad

I like OpenSCAD for teaching the rules of semicolons and curly braces. Within 20 minutes, students can write programs, learn about transformations, and see the results of misplaced semicolons and curly braces without worrying about other semantics. In other words, OpenSCAD is a great tool to teach the fundamentals of the C-family syntax rules to beginners.

But OpenSCAD lacks expressive power. There is no storage of shapes as variables -- everything has to be written as a function. I have found PLasM, based on Python to be much more powerful since python itself can be used in the script.

Does anyone know of a Java-based language, essentially where the underlying CGAL is embedded in Java functions? That would be ideal since I am using Processing and Arduino to teach programming.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want language simpler than C (with regard to not needing pointers, memory allocation, running programs etc.), in order to teach the syntax. Although I hate to recommend it, what about javascript?

Comment: On another topic, "But OpenSCAD lacks expressive power. There is no storage of shapes as variables -- everything has to be written as a function.". Well, few functional programming languages have variables, but they're still pretty powerful!

Comment: All these languages are pretty much calls to underlying routines in CGAL. What I want is an API in Java, but I can't find one.  I don't love functional languages, particularly when there is no optimizer. If you don't optimize calls to CGAL, it's awful.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted a C-like teaching language, but you just wanted a CGAL API in Java.

Answer (score 4):

SolidPython? Not Java based, but might just be what you are looking for?

It's a python frontend for solid modelling that compiles to OpenSCAD:

https://github.com/SolidCode/SolidPython

Answer (score 3):

What about this - https://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/? It is a set of SWIG bindings for CGAL that supports Python and Java.